# socks-ssh and dynamic port forwarding in go

Tags: go, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel, socks

I have a problem I used the gliderlabs ssh library for implementing the ssh server for my project.
My project is a ssh server that only works for ssh tunneling or dynamic port forwarding (socks proxy).
I read the documents and implement everything that I learned but it seems to not work for me.

Implementing local port forwarding
And remote port forwarding and both at the same time and I was expecting that I using it to get socks proxy

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.